# How rotate html table from horizontal to vertical?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-5

I have made the seating of the bus horizontally. This is done through a table. However, the table is now in a horizontal variant. For mobile phones, I need to make it vertical without messing up my code.

I tried to do it through transform(rotate90deg), the desired result is obtained, but the table merges with the text. How do I move the table down using transform(rotate90deg) or is there another css solution?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<table class="">
                    <!--TODO переключнение этажей, подсветка занятых мест, подсветка выбранных мест-->
                    <tr v-for="stroka in mergeFlights.find(trip => trip.id_trip===busTriptId).bus_config[floor]" :key="stroka">
                      <td v-for="seat in stroka" :key="seat"
                        :rowspan="seat.split('+')[1]" 
                        :colspan="seat.split('+')[2]" 
                        align="center">
                        <div v-if="seat.split('+')[3].replace('_', '') !== ''" :class="seat.split('+')[0]" :id="'seat_'+seat.split('+')[3].replace('_', '')">{{seat.split('+')[3].replace('_', '')}}</div>
                        <div v-else-if="seat.split('+')[0] == 'voditel'" :class="seat.split('+')[0]" :id="'seat_'+seat.split('+')[3].replace('_', '')">{{seat.split('+')[3].replace('_', '')}}</div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
```

[bus scheme horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJZ7u.png)

[bus scheme vertical with css transform rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QerDI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can add css style to your

```
 <td style = "display: flex; flex-direction: row">
```

or set class name and do it in your css file.